# Nodemailer and Outlook 365, 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful not meet criteria

Tags: node.js, azure, email, outlook, nodemailer

I am trying to send emails from my outlook account ( office 365 email ) to myself/ to others in my organization. And from my email to my users that may or may not be on office.

I am using Nodejs and Typescript and this is all happening on the server from my own email (our organizations email). So this should require no human interaction/ the access token or whatever shouldn't expire, need manual setting but rather this should be automatic or set once.

I tried the following setup

```
   const mailOptions = {
        from: "FROM@DOMAIN.AI",
        to: "TO@DOMAIN.AI",
        subject: req.title,
        text: req.contents,
      };

      const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

```
export const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "Outlook365",
  auth: {
    user: "FROM@DOMAIN.AI",
    pass: "pass",
  },
});
```

This is the error I am getting

```
[Node] error:   Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [VI1PR0501CA0022.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com]
```

This is happening on localhost while developing locally, but later I am gonna deploy this to heroku.

What I tried:

1. [Tried this solution and enabled Authenticated SMPT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59735571/13440079)
2. Tried using OAUTH and registering an azure project, but there are no resources on how to do SERVER-TO-SERVER communication instead of client to server.

What I need to happen:

1. I have email A in organization and we have a shared inbox B. Ideally I'd be able to send email from B to B ( when user sends us a message I want it to be received in the shared inbox)
2. Be able to send from B (shared inbox ) to other users outside of our organization (our apps users)

After hours of searching and reading the docs, I am unable to find whether or not this is possible. All solutions mention Azure while I don't even use Azure in my app. I just need to send emails via our business email (shared inbox email) to ourself and to our users. I don't use any of the azure services, the docs are huge and are hard to navigate so I have no idea what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the Azure Security Defaults by toggling the Enable Security Defaults to No.

- Sign in to the Azure portal as a Security administrator. Conditional Access administrator, or Global administrator,
- Browse to Azure Active Directory Properties
- Select Manage security defaults.
- Set the Enable security defaults toggle to No.
- Select Save.

You need to wait for some time (couple of minutes), and the problem will be solved.

Comment: This solution means you're disabling security for all emails under that domain and that's a really bad idea - how can this be done for a single email only?

Answer (score 0):

Is Multi-factor authentication enabled.? Then you have to generate app password and use that