# OAuth 2L to Microsoft Outlook account/ Azure? Service accounts in azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, nodemailer

Trying to get nodemailer to work with Outlook and to send emails from the outlook email. I need the private key, access key, and the serviceClient, preferably that don't expire. And I see no way of getting those for Azure, for google it was simple enough, I just got the service account but the Azure doesn't have that option, only has client secret and certificates.

I need something like this

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'Outlook365',
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: 'MYOUTLOOKEMAIL@DOMAIN.COM',
        serviceClient: '113600000000000000000',
        privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBg...',
        accessToken: 'ya29.Xx_XX0xxxxx-xX0X0XxXXxXxXXXxX0x',
        expires: 1484314697598
    }
});
```

[This is the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143722/nodemailer-and-outlook-365-535-5-7-139-authentication-unsuccessful-not-meet-cri)

What is necessary to obtain service account like information from Microsoft/ Azure for my usecase? I probably have to register an app with them but I found no way of getting a service account. I need it for SERVER-TO-SERVER communication so no human interaction.